# Inexplicable SQL Query Result in Cosmos DB Data Explorer

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with ca. 7.000 documents that have been moved over to a new database (to take advantage of Index v2 and database throughput provisioning).

The Query

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id)  FROM c WHERE c._DAT.KursFrei._v = "RD18-G 06"
```

yields the following (correct) result:

```
[
    72
]
```

yet this query for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c._DAT.KursFrei._v FROM c
```

only shows the following output:

```
[
"NFS 16 BW",
"G 04 2018",
"NFS 15",
"NFS 17 BW",
"NFS 17",
"G 05 2018",
"G 05 2015",
"RDF 07",
"RDF 07 "
]
```

The constrained value from the first query does not even show up.

```
SELECT VALUE c._DAT.KursFrei._v FROM c
```

only shows 149 results, while

```
SELECT COUNT(VALUE) c._DAT.KursFrei._v FROM c
```

correctly shows `6891`

- Cross-Partition-Query is enabled
- "Query Results per Page" is set to 10000 (Unlimited still seems to default to 100)
- **All** Query Results are as expected when run against the old, non-partitioned collection
- I have not yet tried to run the Queries from my Application

Here are my index settings:

```
{
"indexingMode": "consistent",
"automatic": true,
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*",
        "indexes": [
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "Number",
                "precision": -1
            },
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "String",
                "precision": -1
            },
            {
                "kind": "Spatial",
                "dataType": "Point"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"excludedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/_OLD/*"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated the basic functionality of the Data Explorer from the Azure Portal locally within my application. Basically I'm just looping an SQL String through `CreateDocumentQuery()` and calling `.ToString()` on all objects in the resulting feed.

As I expected:

- all queries show the correct and expected results
- queries execute orders of magnitude faster than in the portal

This confirms my initial assumption, that the Data Explorer just sent me on a wild goose chase and in it's current state is not only a hassle to use, but virtually useless.